# CSS Float Working in All Browsers Except IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

I have a website that renders perfectly in Safari, FF, Chrome, and Opera.  However, in IE, my website renders slightly off.

HTML:

```
<div align="center" id="headerdiv"><div id="log"><font id="subtitleAttribs"     onclick="login()">Login أدخل حساب</font></div>
<a class="infoHme"><font id="titleAttribs" onclick="home()">T h e<font color="#999999" size="6px"> | </font>A r t i s a n a t<font color="#999999" size="6px"> | </font>N e t w o r k</font><span>Home دار</span></a>
<div id="lang"><font id="subtitleAttribs" onclick="arb()">العربية</font><font color="#999999"> | </font><font id="subtitleAttribs" onclick="eng()">English</font></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#log
{
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
#lang
{
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
}
#titleAttribs
{
  color: #6699cc;
  font-size: 26px;
}
#headerdiv
{
  background-color: #faf8cc;
  margin: 0px 45px 0px 45px;
}
```

In my code snippet there are four parts.  First, "headerdiv" is the container.  Second, "log" is the div that should be on the left.  Third, "titleAttribs" is text that sits in the middle.  Fourth, "lang" is the div that should be on the right.

"log" and "lang" float so that they are on each side of the "titleAttribs" text.  My problem is that in IE "lang" ends up rendering below "log" and "titleAttribs" on the right.  I test my code with a Mac so it is hard for me to test in IE.  When I use a PC and run the .html and .css files in IE9, everything renders just fine.  However, when I go to my website from the internet, IE has the rendering problem, which makes even more difficult for me to resolve.

Would anyone know an easy way to correct this issue without having to make too many changes.  I understand that I could add widths, however I tried with no luck.  Also, the website url is: 
    http://www.imkenliya.com/artisan_network.html

If you run the website in IE, you will notice that the English language button below the search box is not in the yellow banner to the right of the title, which is the rendering problem.

Thanks,

Comment: do you mind posting maybe a link or a jsfiddle?

Comment: @mostly it might be due to extra width i IE , so please use developer tool bar ad check

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried changing the widths, and I used the developer tool in IE, but I could not get the same look that I get in all of the other browsers.  I even tried to float all three div tags to the left, and then change their widths to mimic a full bar across the top of the webpage.  However, it looked pretty bad when using different sized browser windows.  Luckily I have an alert stating to use any browser other than IE.  Mainly this is because of CSS3 transition.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem through persistent trial and error.  Basically, IE read my html differently from the other browsers.  By ordering the information in my html page differently, IE was able to render it properly.  The ordering follows:

container, div float: left, div float: right, middle info

Originally, I had the following:

container, div float: left, middle info, div float: right

This seemed logical, however not to IE.  Additionally, the other browsers still render my html properly.

Answer (score -1):

Use a CSS reset sheet (like this one => http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Also separate styles from your HTML markup (ditch div align="center" and the font tag. Replace them with proper CSS).

If this doesn't solve it, please provide a link to the site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  The reset sheet did not solve the problem, but your comment about cleaning up my html got me to do some Spring cleaning.  Anyway, IE still doesn't know how to portray my website, but at least all of the other browsers do.